# "In a distributed environment, one does not use multithreding" - Why?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, distributed-computing, distributed-system

I am working on a platfor that hosts small Java applications, all of which currently uses a single thread, living inside a Docker engine, consuming data from a Kafka server and logging to a central DB.

Now, I need to put another Java application to this platform. This app at hand uses multithreading relatively heavily, I already tested it inside a Docker container and it works perfectly there, so I'm ready to deploy it on the platform where it would be scaled manually, that is, some human would define the number of containers that would be started, each of them containing an instance of this app.

My Architect has an objection, saying that "In a distributed environment we never use multithreading". So now, I have to refactor my application eliminating any thread related logic from it, making it single threaded. I requested a more detailed reasoning from him, but he yells "If you are not aware of this principle, you have no place near Java".

Is it really a mistake to use a multithreaded Java application in a distributed system - a simple cluster with ten or twenty physical machines, each hosting a number of virtual machines, which then runs Docker containers, with Java applications inside them.

Honestly, I don't see the problem of multithreading inside a container.
Is it really a mistake or somehow "forbidden"?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry you have to work with a bully.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Not just any bully, a close-minded **unthinking** bully bent on forcing adherence to misguided cargo-cult aphorisms.  It's like saying, "If your house has multiple mini-split A/C units instead of one central A/C unit, you can't use a socket wrench to fix your A/C problems!"  Because, "If you are not aware of this principle, you have no place near Java" really means, "I have no idea what I'm talking about."  What rectal database did **THAT** come from?!?!  And yes, I hope he reads this.

Comment: In fact, distributed application is always multithreaded. Even when each node is single-threaded, the whole multi-node cluster is multithreaded. So making single node multithreaded would not things more complex, but can make  life easier.
In short, I would not let your architect to hang about near Java.

Comment: It's silly to use absolutes like this. I mean, Elasticsearch is distributed and heavily multithreaded, so I guess there is at least one counter argument.

Answer (score 2):

When you write for example a web application that will run in a Java EE application server, then normally you should not start up your own threads in your web application. The application server will manage threads, and will allocate threads to process incoming requests on the server.

However, there is no hard rule or reason why it is never a good idea to use multi-threading in a distributed environment.

There are advantages to making applications single-threaded: the code will be simpler and you won't have to deal with difficult concurrency issues.

But "in a distributed environment we never use multithreading" is not necessarily always true and "if you are not aware of this principle, you have no place near Java" sounds arrogant and condescending.

Answer (score 1):

I guess he only tells you this as using a single thread eliminates multi threading and data ordering issues.
There is nothing wrong with multithreading though.

Answer (score 1):

Distributed systems usually have tasks that are heavily I/O bound.

If I/O calls are blocking in your system

The only way to achieve concurrency within the process is spawning new threads to do other useful work. (Multi-threading).

- The caveat with this approach is that, if they are too many threads
  in flight, the operating system will spend too much time context
  switching between threads, which  is wasteful work.

If I/O calls are Non-Blocking in your system

Then you can avoid the Multi-threading approach and use a single thread to service all your requests. (read about event-loops or Java's Netty Framework or NodeJS)

The upside for single thread approach

1. The OS does not any wasteful thread context switches.
2. You will NOT run into any concurrency problems like dead locks or race conditions.

The downside is that

1. It is often harder to code/think in a non-blocking fashion
2. You typically end up using more memory in the form of blocking queues.

Answer (score 0):

What? We use RxJava and Spring Reactor pretty heavily in our application and it works pretty fine. You can't work with threads across two JVMs anyway. So just make sure that your logic is working as you expect on a single JVM.